# Can't inherit my protocol (Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11)

Tags: swift, protocols, key-value-observing

I created a small protocol for binding block (it's some cycle for KVO in `Swift`)
Code is here:

```
typealias storedClosure = (object: Any) -> Void

protocol BindingProtocol {
    var binders: [String : storedClosure]! { get set }
    func bind(string: String, block: storedClosure)
}

extension BindingProtocol {
    mutating func bind(string: String, block: storedClosure) {
        if binders == nil {
            binders = [String : storedClosure]()
        }
        binders[string] = block
    }
}
```

After I try to inherit this protocol I get `Xcode` crashed or compilation error like `Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11`

```
class View : UIView, BindingProtocol {
    var binders: [String : (object: Any) -> Void]!
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a problem with your property, but your method...

```
protocol BindingProtocol {
    var binders: [String : storedClosure]! { get set }
    func bind(string: String, block: storedClosure) //<--- 1.This
}


extension BindingProtocol {
    mutating func bind(string: String, block: storedClosure) { //<--- 2.This
        if binders == nil {
            binders = [String : storedClosure]()
        }
        binders[string] = block
    }
}
```

You defined a method as a normal method at point 1 and implement it as a mutating at point 2.

They have the same signature but in fact are two different methods. In this case, Swift didn't found the right one to call. It's a common problem I've been living when I use protocol with default implementation.

One solution is just change...

```
protocol BindingProtocol {
    ...
    //From
    //func bind(string: String, block: storedClosure) 

    //To
    mutating func bind(string: String, block: storedClosure) 
}
```